# Java Cucumber - junit does not run any test

Tags: java, cucumber, junit

could you tell me why "mvn test" or "mvn verify" does not run any test ? Maybe any dependency is missing ?

```
package cucumber.Options;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/java/features",
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/jsonReports/cucumber-report.json",
                "html:target/jsonReports/cucumber-report.html"},
        glue= {"stepDefs"},
        stepNotifications = true,
        monochrome = true
        )
public class TestRunner {
}
```

======================================================

Feature: test of a webpage

```
  @desktop
  Scenario: Test landing page
    Given Customer accepts cookie consent
    And I click "OK" button at the bottom of the page
```

Pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Cucumber</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>7.12.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.11</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/picocontainer/picocontainer -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/picocontainer/picocontainer -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/picocontainer/picocontainer -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/picocontainer/picocontainer -->


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/picocontainer/picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>picocontainer</groupId>
            <artifactId>picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.monochromata.cucumber/reporting-plugin -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java8 -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/maven-cucumber-reporting -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/maven-cucumber-reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.5</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>26.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.9.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>


                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*TestRunner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>5.7.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>Cucumber</projectName>
                            <!-- optional, per documentation set this to "true" to bypass generation of Cucumber Reports entirely, defaults to false if not specified -->
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <!-- output directory for the generated report -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                            <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jsonReports</inputDirectory>
                            <jsonFiles>
                                <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                                <param>**/*.json</param>
                            </jsonFiles>
                            <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->

                            <!-- optional, set true to group features by its Ids -->
                            <mergeFeaturesById>false</mergeFeaturesById>
                            <!-- optional, set true to get a final report with latest results of the same test from different test runs -->
                            <mergeFeaturesWithRetest>false</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
                            <!-- optional, set true to fail build on test failures -->
                            <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Mvn command

```
$ mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.example:Cucumber:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.projectlombok:lombok:jar is either LATEST or RELEASE (both of them are being deprecated) @ line 91, column 22
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar -> version 4.4.0 vs 4.8.3 @ line 111, column 21
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.projectlombok:lombok:jar -> version RELEASE vs 1.18.26 @ line 116, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin @ line 254, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------< org.example:Cucumber >------------------------
[INFO] Building Cucumber 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ Cucumber ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ Cucumber ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ Cucumber ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\Cucumber\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Cucumber ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- surefire:3.0.0:test (default-test) @ Cucumber ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.895 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-06T22:26:29+02:00
```

Comment: Are you sure that the path on maven-surefire-plugin is correct? I would suggest trying to place a relative or absolute path, without asteriks, to be sure. (If that's indeed the problem, I will transform it in an answer)

Comment: What do you mean by saying path ? Which path ?

Comment: Where you have "**/*TestRunner.java". Are you sure it is correct?